# Get service (init.d) information on linux

Tags: c++, linux, service, centos

I want to list the services on my server and they status in cpp.
But I don't know if it is possible to get those information?
I try to use libproc, but it list application on /proc/ and only running application

So my question is; is it posssible to get service running like the cmd service --status-all?

the output will be someting like :
dovecot (pid  xxxx) is running...
httpd is stopped

Thank you.

Comment: `cat $(which service)` then it shouldn't be too hard to port to C++. Or easier yet, call it through `popen()` and parse its output.

Comment: I am ashame to be so dumb. thank you for your answer!

Comment: Don't be ashamed or belittle yourself, it happens to everyone to miss "obvious" things once in a while. ;)